# handleCategoryClick and handleSearchChange in React app are not retaining the funcionality across different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

The `handleCategoryClick` and `handleSearchChange` functions function correctly on the landing page. The navigation to the Testing or Articles components also works as expected.

Once in the Testing component, I can see the content "Hello" along with the `<div className="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2 custom-class1">` that contains the categories and the search bar. Unfortunately, if I try to use the `handleCategoryClick` function within the `Testing` component, it does not work. The same issue occurs with the search bar as well, where typing something does not trigger any action.

Another issue is that when I click on any category, such as "Mexico" it displays the corresponding cards as expected. However, if I try to use the search bar, it doesn't work properly. It only shows me the results from the selected category.  I passes the functions as props to the components, still do not work.

What I expect is that when I navigate to the `Testing` component, I should be able to search for something else and have the content of `Testing` hidden. Instead, I should see the cards based on what I type. The same applies to filtering categories. The content of Testing should be hidden, and the cards should be displayed according to the selected category.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer'
import filteredData from './components/data/filteredData';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';




function Testing({ handleCategoryClick, handleSearchChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Articles({ handleCategoryClick, handleSearchChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Wasabito</h1>
    </div>
  );
}


function App() {
  const itemsPerPage = 9;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

   const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  }; 

  const handleCategoryClick = (category) => {
    setSelectedCategory(category);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const filteredCards = filteredData.filter((item) => {
    const { category, text, description } = item;
    const lowerCaseSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    return (
      (!selectedCategory || selectedCategory === 'All' || category === selectedCategory) &&
      ( category.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) || 
        text.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
        description.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm))
    );
  });

  const totalCards = filteredCards.length;
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCards / itemsPerPage);

  const indexOfLastCard = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstCard = indexOfLastCard - itemsPerPage;
  const currentCards = filteredCards.slice(indexOfFirstCard, indexOfLastCard);
  const pageNumbers = Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, i) => i + 1);


  return (
    <Router>
      <div>        
        {selectedCategory === null && (
          <div className="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white" 
            style={{ background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #00c6ff, #0072ff)', marginTop: '20px' }}>
            Mas Verificaciones
          </div>
        )}
        
        <div className="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2 custom-class1">
          <nav className="nav d-flex justify-content-between px-3">
            <h2><a href="/"><img src="logo.png"  alt=" "/></a></h2>          
            {["Estados Unidos", "Mexico", "America Latina", "Resto del Mundo", "Covid-19", "Salud", "Medio Ambiente", "Guerra en Ucrania"].map((cat) => (
              <span
                className={`nav-link-second p-2 d-none d-md-block ${selectedCategory === cat ? "active" : ""}`}
                key={cat}
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => handleCategoryClick(cat)}
              >
                {cat}
              </span>
            ))}
          </nav>
        </div>
        
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Search..."
                value={searchTerm}
                onChange={handleSearchChange}             
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>     
              
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <>
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    {currentCards.map((item) => (
                      <div className="col-md-4 mb-3" key={item.id}>
                        <div className="card">
                          <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="frame-color"></div>
                            <p className="card-text">{item.category}</p>
                            <p className="card-text">{item.description}</p>
                            <Link to={item.pagePath} className="btn btn-primary">
                              {item.text}
                            </Link>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
  
                <nav aria-label="...">
                  <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
                    <li className={`page-item ${currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
                      <a
                        className="page-link"
                        href="#"
                        onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}
                        tabIndex="-1"
                      >
                        Previous
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
                      <li
                        key={number}
                        className={`page-item ${currentPage === number ? 'active' : ''}`}
                      >
                        <a
                          className="page-link"
                          href="#"
                          onClick={() => setCurrentPage(number)}
                        >
                          {number}
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                    <li
                      className={`page-item ${currentPage === totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''}`}
                    >
                      <a
                        className="page-link"
                        href="#"
                        onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}
                      >
                        Next
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>       
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/testing/:id" element={<Testing handleCategoryClick={handleCategoryClick} handleSearchChange={handleSearchChange} />} />
          <Route path="/articles/:id" element={<Articles handleCategoryClick={handleCategoryClick} handleSearchChange={handleSearchChange} />} />
        </Routes>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}


export default App; 

//components/data/filteredData.js
const filteredData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    category: "Mexico",
    pagePath: "/articles/1",
    text: "Learn More",
    description: "loren ipsum loren ipssum loren ipsum"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    category: "Estados Unidos",
    pagePath: "/testing/1",
    text: "Learn More",
    description: "loren ipsum loren ipssum loren ipsum"
  },]
```

I passed the functions as props to the components, I change this code without success.

```
const filteredCards = filteredData.filter((item) => {
  const { category, text, description } = item;
  const lowerCaseSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  return (
    (!selectedCategory ||
      selectedCategory === "All" ||
      category === selectedCategory) && // <-- this conditional
    (category.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      text.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      description.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm))
  );
}); for this one 
const filteredCards = filteredData.filter((item) => {
  const { category, text, description } = item;
  const lowerCaseSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  return (
    (!selectedCategory ||
      selectedCategory === "All" ||
      category === selectedCategory) || // <-- be more inclusive
    (category.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      text.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      description.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm))
  );
});
```